# kubernetes golang client: Get containers in a pod

Tags: go, kubernetes

I have the following to exec into a pod to run a command

```
fmt.Println("Running the command:", command)
parameterCodec := runtime.NewParameterCodec(scheme)
req.VersionedParams(&corev1.PodExecOptions{
    Command:   strings.Fields(command),
    Stdin:     stdin != nil,
    Stdout:    true,
    Stderr:    true,
    TTY:       false,
}, parameterCodec)
```

I'm looking to run the same command but adding the `Container` option which is a string. I'm having a hard time figuring how how I can list all the containers in a pod.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

got it

```
pod, err := clientset.CoreV1().Pods("default").Get(podname, metav1.GetOptions{})
if err != nil {
    return "", err
}

fmt.Println(pod.Spec.Containers[0])
```

Comment: please add import statements as well